# Casting to unsigned char in C

Tags: c++, c, casting

I am facing a following problem: When trying to do cast to an unsigned char I get unexpected values. The code that I am using:

```
unsigned char MyVal1  = ((0xF1E3 && 0xff00) >> 8);
unsigned char MyVal2 = (unsigned char)((0xF1E3 && 0xff00) >> 8);
unsigned char MyVal3 = (unsigned char)((0xF1E3 && 0xff));
```

I am storing all three variables in an array.

The output I am getting (looking at the values in array; array is unsigned char array):

```
0x00 
0x00
0x01
```

while I was expecting:

```
0xF1 
0xF1
0xE3
```

Could someone be kind to help me out in what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Operators `&&` and `&` do not work the same on integers. Your operands are first converted to bool (zero/nonzero) and then `and`ed together.

Comment: Checkmate.... It has been a long day and I totally forgot that I was not using bitwise operator.... Much appreciated.....

Answer (score 10):

`&&` is the *boolean* and operator; it gives `1` if both its operands are non-zero and `0` otherwise.  You want the *bitwise* and operator, `&`, which gives `1` or `0` in each bit of its operands.